# Why is the type Object with Ordering[LocalDate] inferred in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I don't understand why the type `Object with Ordering[LocalDate]` is inferred in such a straightforward case :

```
@ import java.time.LocalDate
@ implicit val ord = new Ordering[LocalDate] {
      override def compare(x: LocalDate, y: LocalDate): Int = x.compareTo(y)
    }
ord: Object with Ordering[LocalDate] = cmd9$$anon$1@61b405c7
```

Comment: What do you think it should be inferred as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are creating an anonymous class by using a type refinement. The following line:

```
implicit val ord = new Ordering[LocalDate] {
  override def compare(x: LocalDate, y: LocalDate): Int = x.compareTo(y)
}
```

Gets transformed to:

```
implicit val ord = new AnyRef with Ordering[LocalDate] {
  override def compare(x: LocalDate, y: LocalDate): Int = x.compareTo(y)
}
```

`Ordering` is a trait, and as such, it can't be instantiated directly. So the compiler adds the `AnyRef`, which gets displayed as "Object" in the REPL.